# How to find/cut for only the filename from an output of ls -lrt in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, cut

I want the file name from the output of `ls -lrt`, but I am unable to find a file name. I used the command below, but it doesn't work.

```
$cmd=' -rw-r--r-- 1 admin u19530 3506 Aug  7 03:34 sla.20120807033424.log';
my $result=`cut -d, -f9 $cmd`;
print "The file name is $result\n";
```

The result is blank. I need the file name as `sla.20120807033424.log`

---

So far, I have tried the below code, and it works for the filename.

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $dir = <dir path>;
opendir (my $DH, $dir) or die "Error opening $dir: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$dir/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
print "the file is $sorted_files[0] \n";
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to parse something as inherently unparseable as output of `ls`, when you can get all the information more efficiently and without any nasty corner-cases with `glob` and `stat` functions?

Comment: Why don't you use perl's `glob` function? Parsing the output of `ls` will get you in trouble at some point. (And `stat` if you need the file's metadata.) And if you find yourself having to use `cut` inside a Perl script, read about `split` instead.

Comment: @JanHudec Could be he needs the `-rt` part. `glob` won't do that.

Comment: @Ariel: No. But the `stat` (or `-M`) builtin function and few comparisons *will*.

Comment: Or in better words, **what are you trying to actually achieve?** Parsing of text intended for human consumption is rarely a good idea, but if you provide more context, there is probably a much better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it harder for yourself by using `-l`. This will do what you want

```
print((`ls -brt`)[0]);
```

But it is generally better to avoid shelling out unless Perl can't provide what you need, and this can be done easily

```
print "$_\n" for (sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } glob "*")[0];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for all the suggestions.. i have tried so far the below code and it works for the filename: I m sharing the code below:

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl


my $dir = <dir path>;



opendir(my $DH, $dir) or die "Error opening $dir: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$dir/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
print "the file is $sorted_files[0] \n";

Comment: @pauler: That is a lot longer than my solution using `glob`. Why do you prefer it?

Comment: Glob wasnt wroking for me, the glob was giving me the oldest of ls -rt o/p, but i needed was the latest file from ls -lrt o/p

Comment: @pauler: I apologize. In that case the sort just needs to be reversed. I have updated my solution

Comment: great i got tht... nw trying to grep the modified time, Thanks .. this is quite simpler compared to my code.

Comment: It's hard (i.e. system-specific) to create a proper glob expression for a directory other than the current directory. That's why I didn't use `glob`.

Comment: Secondly, that calls `stat` waaaaay too many times. More than twice as many as needed. Possibly much more.

Answer (score 8):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
use File::stat       qw( stat );
use List::Util       qw( reduce );

my ($oldest) =
   map $_ ? $_->[0] : undef,                              # 4. Get rid of stat data.
   reduce { $a->[1]->mtime < $b->[1]->mtime ? $a : $b }   # 3. Find one with oldest mtime.
   map [ $_, scalar(stat($_)) ],                          # 2. stat each file.
   File::Find::Rule                                       # 1. Find relevant files.
      ->maxdepth(1)                                       #       Don't recurse.
      ->file                                              #       Just plain files.
      ->in('.');                                          #       In whatever dir.
```

- [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule)
- [File::stat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3astat)
- [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil)

Comment: @Ariel, done. Each line is rather independent of the others, so that was easy.

Comment: @ikegami: can u let me know which shebang statement ur using for this code

Comment: @pauler, I didn't use one. Why do you care where I installed my Perl?

Answer (score 1):

if the name of log file is under your control, ie., free of space or other special characters, perhaps a quick & dirty job will do:

```
my $cmd=' -rw-r--r-- 1 admin u19530 3506 Aug  7 03:34 sla.20120807033424.log more more';
my @items = split ' ', $cmd;
print "log filename is : @items[8..$#items]";
print "\n";
```

Comment: thanks for helping out, but your answer assumes that the file does not contain a blank, could you use your Perl skills (that I don't have) to make it "element 8 and all following"?

Comment: It is just a quick solution to the OP specific situation, that he has a log file system in his control. If there is a need to include element 8 and following, see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it reliably with `-lrt` - if you were willing to choose other options you could do it.

BTW you can still sort by reverse time with `-rt` even without the `-l`.

Also if you must use ls, you should probably use `-b`.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. It's not possible to parse output of `ls` reliably, period. You see, most unices are crazy enough to allow a *newline* character in filename and that will break anything that does not support NUL-termination.

Comment: @JanHudec When I said 'other options' I meant other programs (alternatives). But in any case the `-b` will help with newlines.

Comment: @JanHudec I just tried it and the newline was printed as `\n`

Comment: You are right, it will print escape sequences with `-b`. Which makes it parseable, but quite a lot of work to actually do.

Comment: @JanHudec Sure - I agree this isn't a good way to do it unless it's for a quick and dirty one-off. And it also seems to me that it's time for you to post some perl code using `stat` that will do this including the reverse time sort :) The OP seems AWOL but I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: I am really waiting for OP to come back and say what they really need to do. Maybe they have an FTP server with some data that publishes output of this command or some similarly crazy setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cmd = ' -rw-r--r-- 1 admin u19530 3506 Aug  7 03:34 sla.20120807033424.log';

$cmd =~ / ( \S+) $/x or die "can't find filename in string " ;
my $filename = $1 ;

print $filename ;
```

Disclaimer - this won't work if filename has spaces and probably under other circumstances.   The OP will know the naming conventions of the files concerned.  I agree there are more robust ways not using `ls -lrt`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe as this:

```
ls -lrt *.log | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
```

Comment: and what if the filename contains, say, a space? (like `my resume.txt`)