# How to get the last modified date for a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, ls

How to get the last modified date for a file in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)?

I am able to get the last modified file, but I need the files of the same date from a directory using Perl. I have the solution for getting the last modified file in Stack Overflow question *[How to find/cut for only the filename from an output of ls -lrt in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840171)*.

But how do I fetch the output of `ls -lrt` for the latest date instead of time?

Answer (score 11):

This is a case for the [`stat Function`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) in Perl -- parsing output from shell commands is a bit unportable, very inefficient and plain wrong.

```
my $mtime = (stat $file)[9];
```

If you are really desperate, you should use the `split function`, of course:

```
my $mtimeAsString = join "" (split /\s+/, (`ls -lrt $file`)[0], 8)[5,6];
    # using only the first line of input
```

Feel free to compare the readability…

Comment: I am using stat itself. I use stat as below:
my $dir = <dir path>;
        opendir(my $DH, $dir) or die "Error opening $dir: $!";
        my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$dir/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
        #print Dumper(%files);
        closedir($DH);

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `ls -lrt` to get the last modified date of a file in Perl... you're doing it wrong.

The right solution is using the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function, or the [`File::Stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) module which wraps it. Both will give you a bunch of data on a file, including all three of the utimes.

Answer (score 2):

`stat` is traditional. Either use the standard builtin

```
my $mtime = (stat $filename)[9];
```

Or use the [`File::stat`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3astat) convenience wrapper which provides more memorable access

```
use File::stat;

my $mtime = stat($filename)->mtime;
```